# Bootstrap toggable menu icon doesn't work on small device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i added at my hoe page a navbar with toggable icon on small screen; It is the typical navbar of bootstrap.
I have the problem that when i go on developer tool and resize the screen in order to test the responsive part, happen that the icon doesn't toggle, it is like is not active.

Any help?

Here is the code:

```
<nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navmenu">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="images/art-of-hair.png"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hair Styles</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="">About</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

and css:

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Alice', serif;
}

#header {
    height:200px;

}

#logo {
    width: 300px;
    height:150px;
}

#navmenu {
    margin:30px 120px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of toggle, I guess you also need some jQuery to make the toggle function.

Maybe try something like this:

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#navmenu").slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I taught that it was automatic with the link to the external file of js and jquery

Comment: Well i dont know which package you're using now, cause there are many options. Does this work for you or not?

Comment: I fixed a part of the issue related to the button click, but when i click the menu is showed over the jumbotron inside the #contents, whereas i want the contents to is pulled down when the menu toggle in and to turn back when toggle out. At the moment it doesn't work as i want.

Comment: I think i dont understand you. Is there any link where i can find your code/website? Then i will take a look and hopefully solve your problem.